# How can I modify an extensions badge in jQuery?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

Can I use jQuery to add `Removed += 1` like it has been used in the top function? Can I make it only add 1 if the attribute was removed?

```
window.onload = function() {

    let Removed = 0
    const anchorElements = document.getElementsByTagName('A')

    for (element of anchorElements) {
        if (!element.getAttribute('ping')) continue
            console.log("Removed ping: " + element.getAttribute('ping'))
                element.removeAttribute('ping')
                Removed += 1
                chrome.extension.sendMessage(Removed)
    }
}

link();

function link(){

    jQuery("a[onclick*='ga']").removeAttr('onclick');
    jQuery("a[onclick*='_gaq.push']").removeAttr('onclick');
    jQuery("link[rel*='pingback']").removeAttr('rel');

}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking because we don't know where this code runs, and where you want your jQuery to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that extensions use dedicated API [browserAction.setBadgeText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/setBadgeText) to interact with the extensions badge from privileged scripts (not content scripts).

JQuery is used in your content and does not have access to above API.

You can use [runtime.sendMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage) to pass the request to the background script.